# MySql Query for Current Date

Tags: php, mysql

I have s MySQL Query where I want to pull data from my database but base it on the current month information

```
FROM lbs_trace_etrack WHERE (lbs_agent = '$slfirstname' AND DATE (lbs_date) = CURDATE()) ORDER BY lbs_date DESC LIMIT 0,50");
```

This string pulls out the information for the current day.

I have also tried the below string but get no results from it:

```
FROM lbs_trace_etrack WHERE (lbs_agent = '$slfirstname' AND MONTH(lbs_date) =  (MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(lbs_date) = YEAR(NOW())
```

My table date format is as follow 2016-08-02

Comment: Is `lbs_date` actually a date, datetime, or timestamp field?

Comment: @ Mike Brant yes it is in the format 2016-08-02 as stated

Comment: Wasn't sure if that was just string format or an actual date formatted field as it makes no sense to call DATE() on a date field.

Comment: Please paste the full query and try to format it a bit so it's easier to read.
Also try removing parts of the query that you are not testing (for example the llbs_agent = '$slfirstname'). Try to only focus in the part where you are having trouble (getting the records of the current month). This way you make it easier for yourself and for other people.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `lbs_agent` is a DATE field type as mentioned in comments, you could do this (note I am just showing the pertinent date part of your WHERE clause):

```
WHERE lbs_agent >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01')
```

It is important that you do not use a function call on the left (field definition) side of the WHERE comparison, as you will then not be able to leverage any index on that field. Doing this would require a full table scan with MySQL performing the function on this field for every row in the table such that the comparison can be made.

Feel free to use MySQL functions for the comparison value, as those would be calculated just once when the query is being planned. You would then be able to use an index on the field for quickly filtering the rows in the table that meet the criteria.  From a query execution standpoint, this is basically that same as if your query has this WHERE clause:

```
WHERE lbs_agent >= '2016-08-01'
```

This is as compared to the examples in your question which would be executed as:

```
WHERE DATE(lbs_date) = '2016-08-03'
```

and

```
WHERE MONTH(lbs_date) = 8 AND YEAR(lbs_date) = 2016
```

Both of these would require full table scan since the values derived from the field are not able to be determined until the row is scanned.

Answer (score 0):

Or using PHP variables as so:

```
<?php
$start = date('Y-m-01'); // FIRST DAY OF CURRENT MONTH
$end = date("Y-m-t", strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))); // LAST DAY OF CURRENT MONTH
$sql = "SELECT * FROM lbs_trace_etrack WHERE lbs_agent = '".$slfirstname."' AND (lbs_date BETWEEN '".$start."' AND '".$end."')";
?>
```

Comment: A valid solution, but OP might need to consider where the date is authoritative.  If for example date values in the DB table are set using the MySQL server's authoritative date and this might vary from the PHP application server's date (i.e. different time zone settings), then this could introduce errors around the month boundaries.  The bottom line is the OP should be consistent about where the date is authoritative.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the following and it works

```
FROM lbs_trace_etrack WHERE lbs_agent = '$slfirstname' AND MONTH(lbs_date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(lbs_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) ORDER BY lbs_date ASC, lbs_time ASC
```

Thanks to all and Tijo for guidance

Comment: This may "work" but it would require a full table scan to execute, so it is not a very optimal answer.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to extract the month, such as `EXTRACT(MONTH from NOW())`

Comment: You cannot meaningfully use `MONTH()` without `YEAR()` if you want to get results for current month rather than results for every `[current month value]` across all years.

Comment: What? I'm not using MONTH() neither YEAR(). What I wrote it the same result as the other answer MONTH(CURDATE())

Comment: I am meaning that you only consider MONTH.  Your clause would simply evaluate as `8`.  If using this in WHERE clause comparison, this would return values from August 2016, August 2015, August 2014, etc. because the MONTH value would match all of these.  Your have to use month values in conjunction with year values if you want a specific month in a specific year.

Comment: I'm using EXTRACT... Plus, I don't see in your answer how you get the month, I thought that was the question.

Comment: My answer does not try to perform any function on the field value itself (this is important if you want to leverage an index on the field).  Instead I use `DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01')` to create a date value representing the first day of the current month.  This is then used to compare against the field value in an index-friendly manner.  Even if you were to extract both month and year from the current date for comparison, your answer would require you to do the same for the field value to have similar values to compare against.  This would require a full table scan.

Answer (score -1):

you can use  following code if it timestamp
MONTH(CURDATE())

Comment: You cannot meaningfully use `MONTH()` without `YEAR()` if you want to get results for current month rather than results for every `[current month value]` across all years.